# Automator with shell script

Tags: bash, macos, automator

I try to solve little task, convert e-books from fb2 to KEPUB (this EPUB extended by Kobo).
For this I create Automator service and when select file in context menu find item allow me to convert.
But my script has issue, if source file have a double extension, like *.fb2.zip then all broken.
This is result of working first tool fb2mobi, which convert file to EPUB. Output file get *.epub extension and lost fb2.
Example:
    source file: someBook.series1.fb2.zip
    fb2mobi result: somebook.series1.epub

[image]

Code in it necessary

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
source $HOME/.bash_profile

for f in "$@"
    do
        basePath=$(dirname "$f")"/"
        outputFileIntermeidate=${f##*/}
        fb2mobi -p KoboAO $f -f epub -o $basePath
        kepubName=${f%.*}".epub"
        willRemove=$kepubName
        kepubify -v ${kepubName} -o $basePath
    rm -fv $willRemove
done
```

I think, best solution it send result of work fb2mobi to kepubify directly, but don't know of possible of it.

Comment: Usually the `.zip` extension means it's a compressed (zip) file and the script would need to extract it before running the conversion.

Comment: You propose do unzip and after it send file to fb2mobi?

Comment: Correct. Although after Unziping you could have multiple files. Depends upon the content of the zip.